# Create and output multiple plots from list

Tags: r

I am attempting to create and output as pdfs a list of 64 items. My data takes the form:

```
QQJAN     List of 64

file1: List of 2
..$x: num [1:161] 96.7 96.8 97.5 ...
..$y: num [1:161] 9.3 10.3 17.3 ...
..................................................................
file64: List of 2
..$x: num [1:161] 42.6 59.9 70.4 ...
..$y: num [1:161] 9.3 10.3 17.3 ...
```

I can do this for any single item in the list using:

```
plot(QQJAN$file1)
```

and can then output these files to my working directory as pdfs, but how can all 64 files in the list be plotted and outputted with their names, i.e. file1.pdf, file 2.pdf etc.

Can the lapply function be used here?

A reproducible example:

```
QQJAN$file1$x=c(1,2,3,4)
QQJAN$file1$y=c(2,4,5,6)

QQJAN$file2$x=c(2,2,3,5)
QQJAN$file2$y=c(2,4,5,6)
```

Comment: Try with `lapply` i.e. `lapply(names(QQJAN), function(x) plot(QQJAN[[x]], ` and specify the file name using `paste0(x, '.pdf'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @akrun. This gives me an error message saying: "Error in xy.coords (x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log): 'x' and 'y' lengths differ. But they shouldn't differ, as x and y both have 161 integers.

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example

Comment: I'm not sure if what I added above is a reproducible example or not, but maybe it can help illustrate the nature of my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `names` of the `list` elements, create the `pdf` file by `paste`ing the individual names with `.pdf`, subset the `list` (`QQJAN[[x]]`), `plot`.

```
 invisible(lapply(names(QQJAN), function(x) {
         pdf(paste0(x, '.pdf'))
          plot(QQJAN[[x]])
         dev.off()}))
```

#### data

```
QQJAN <- structure(list(file1 = structure(list(x = c(6L, 5L, 15L, 11L, 
14L, 19L, 6L, 16L, 17L, 6L, 13L, 8L, 14L, 14L, 7L, 19L, 4L, 1L, 
11L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 15L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 2L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 
8L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 20L), y = c(29L, 23L, 17L, 14L, 
3L, 5L, 24L, 22L, 16L, 21L, 28L, 52L, 28L, 43L, 33L, 60L, 28L, 
18L, 11L, 9L, 30L, 15L, 17L, 8L, 44L, 19L, 57L, 59L, 45L, 30L, 
9L, 13L, 1L, 60L, 39L, 21L, 35L, 50L, 3L, 44L)), .Names = c("x", 
"y")), file2 = structure(list(x = c(11L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 18L, 8L, 17L, 7L, 15L, 19L, 3L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 
15L, 13L, 3L, 6L, 16L, 1L, 20L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 6L, 13L, 
18L, 7L, 18L, 19L, 15L, 13L), y = c(56L, 31L, 40L, 43L, 20L, 
45L, 55L, 8L, 43L, 26L, 7L, 52L, 7L, 31L, 11L, 14L, 55L, 26L, 
4L, 42L, 34L, 44L, 12L, 4L, 30L, 60L, 23L, 44L, 29L, 55L, 6L, 
37L, 11L, 14L, 36L, 52L, 28L, 22L, 31L, 33L)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"))), .Names = c("file1", "file2"))
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you so much @akrun!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested due to lack of a reproducible example:

```
for (i in seq_along(QQJAN)) {
  pdf(sprintf("plot%i.pdf", i)) #or pdf(paste0(names(QQJAN)[i], ".pdf"))
    plot(QQJAN[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

If you are only interested in side effects, such as plotting, a `for` loop is usually appropriate. You should use `lapply` if you need a return value.

Comment: Thank you very much @Roland. This also works very nicely, but I prefer the lapply method as I can understand more easily what it is doing. But many thanks for this great alternative solution.